# QGIS: where are custom color ramps stored?

Tags: qgis, color-ramp

Using QGIS 3.4.0, I have created a new custom color ramp, using:

Settings > Style Manager > Color ramp > green plus sign

I saved the new color ramp as follows:

[image]

The color ramp works just fine.

Out of curiosity, I searched the entire local drive for the new ramp, using the text string (test_example).  Nothing returned.

So, where are these new ramps stored, i.e. folder and file name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting... I opened my `Profiles | default` folder and found **symbology-style.db** (an SQLite file).

It contained `colorramp` Table.

[image]

My `colorramp` table has additional colors such as *Inferno*, *Magma*, etc. (They came from `Viridis` colorramp). So your added `test_example` would be found here, too.

[image]

Comment: Perfect!  Here's an additional bit of info: the user profile location seems to have moved when QGIS upgraded from 2.X to 3.X.  The old location (.qgis2) does not appear to be used with 3.X.  Instead, this thread gives the new 3.X location: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/274358/missing-qgis2-folder